# Как задать точное расстояние между формами?

Tags: html, css

Пишу `</br>`, но он много дает отступа вниз. Как можно уменьшить это расстояние?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Читаем про [`margin`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/margin) либо можно `<br style="line-height: 3px;" />`

pps; в чем смысл задавать такие вопросы?